# Possibility of passing multiple parameters in URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a search-based website, and am trying to pass parameters using SEO-friendly URLs.

Is it possible to pass the following URL and get the URL in CodeIgniter?

```
http://www.example.com/search/prize/10/13/14.5/size/xl/2xl/color/black/white-grey/
```

I am able to create the URL, but I want to get the URL values like `$prize = array("10","13","14.5")`, `$size= array("xl","2xl")`, and `$color = array("black","white-grey")`.

I tried to use the `uri_to_assoc()` function, but it didn't work. I get the following output:

```
[price] => 10,
[13] => 14.5
...
```

which is wrong.

**Note:** I tried to use `$this->uri->segment(1)`, etc., but in this case, the segment position is dynamic.

For example, users may search for only prices of `$10`, so the URL will get changed to:

```
http://www.example.com/search/prize/10/size/xl/2xl/color/black/white-grey/
```

Now the segment position of getting the `size` must be changed. In this case, I want:

```
$prize = array("10");
$size = array("xl", "2xl");
$color = array("black", "white-grey");
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `it didn't worked` How didn't it worked? How did you try to use it? What have you really tried? You're probably looking for `$this->uri->segment_array()`

Comment: @sjagr I added my tried coding, also when trying $this->uri->segment_array(), am getting the each and every values in URL - Not required.

Comment: It certainly is required if you want to get this URI format in a useful way.

Comment: a simple, but not the best way, is to pass parameters like this: `http://www.example.com/search/prize/10_13_14.5/size/xl_2xl/color/black_white-grey/`  then `explode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using quite the unconventional "friendly URI" format. Normally when passing parameters there is a single identifier and then the parameter e.g. `/name/key/name/key/name/key`.

When you use the correct format `/name/key/name/key/name/key` in conjunction with `uri_to_assoc()`, you would get:

```
array(
    'name' => 'key',
    // etc...
)
```

but using something like `/prize/1/2/3/size/s/m/l/color/black/white/grey` would yield:

```
array(
    'prize' => 1,
    2 => 3,
    'size' => 's',
    'm' => 'l',
    // etc...
)
```

Which is useless to you.

You will have to fetch all of the segments individually and *build* your arrays with a `foreach`:

```
$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
$prize = array();
$size = array();
$color = array();
$curKey = '';
foreach ($segments as $seg) {
    if (in_array($seg, array('prize', 'size', 'color'))) {
        $curKey = $seg; continue;
    }
    if (!empty($curKey)) ${$curKey}[] = $seg;
}

// use $prize, $size, and $color as you wish
```

or alternatively using a multi-dimensional array:

```
$parameters = array(
    'prize' => array(),
    'size' => array(),
    'color' => array(),
);
$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
$curKey = '';
foreach ($segments as $seg) {
    if (in_array($seg, array('prize', 'size', 'color'))) {
        $curKey = $seg; continue;
    }
    if (!empty($curKey)) $parameters[$curKey][] = $seg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch all the segments
2. Iterate over them, check each for keywords like `size`, `color`, etc. (make a whitelist)
3. If a keyword is found, assume the segment values until the next keyword segment or the end are the values for that specific keyword (so `xl` and `2xl` will denote the size if preceeded with a keyword `size`, etc.)